# OR-Tools CP-SAT solver: count successive NewBoolVar occurrences

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

In a simple range I try to get the amount of successive assignments for a variable. The values should be between 6-12 or should be 0. For example in the case a hospital has 24 shifts and an employee should work between 6 and 12 hours or not at all.

```
# Build shifts
shifts = {}
for n in all_nurses:
    for d in all_days:
        for s in all_shifts:
            shifts[(n, d, s)] = model.NewBoolVar('shift_n%id%is%i' % (n, d, s))

# Count successive occurrences
for e_count in all_nurses:
    s_count = 0
    while s_count < len(all_shifts):
        model.Add(sum(shifts[e_count, s_count] for s in range(e_count, e_count + 6 == 6) #min
        model.Add(sum(shifts[e_count, s_count] for s in range(e_count, e_count + 12 <= 12) #min
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work since it increases the value with only one, what would be the best approach to check if how many hours have been assigned and increase `s_count` with that value?

Comment: If thats really a hard-constraint, consider formulating it as DFA using [AddAutomaton](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/python/sat/python/cp_model#addautomaton). There should be some examples in the repo. Some motivation/background [is available here](https://sofdem.github.io/art/demassey14cmp.pdf).

Comment: @sascha thanks for the suggestion and docs! I suppose there should be an easier way to solve this supposedly easy task? Is there really no way to count the sum and increase the `s_count` with that value?

Comment: CP-SAT natively supports sum(bool_vars) in [0] U [6..12].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to constrain the sum, you should use [this method](https://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html#CpModel.AddLinearExpressionInDomain)

```
model.AddLinearExpressionInDomain(sum(bool_vars), cp_model.Domain.FromIntervals([0, 0], [6, 12]))
```

If you want to constrain the length of a sequence, you should look at [the shift_scheduling example](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py)

In particular, the soft sequence constraint.
The idea is the following, for every starting point, you want to forbid 010, 0110, 01110, ..., 0111110 and 01111111111110 (0110 means work[start] is false, work[start + 1] is true, work[start + 2] is true, work[start + 3] is false.

To forbid a sequence, just add a nogood, that is a clause (or AddBoolOr containing the negation of the pattern.

in my example bool_or(work[start], work[start + 1].Not(), work[start + 2].Not(), work[start + 3]).

Loop over all starting points and all patterns. And pay attention to the boundary conditions.

Comment: `for e_count in all_nurses:
    shift_min_max_length = cp_model.Domain.FromIntervals([[0, 0], [6, 12]])
    model.AddLinearExpressionInDomain(sum(shifts[e_count, s_count] for s_count in all_shifts, shift_min_max_length)`

Gives no errors, but also no solutions although there should clearly be solutions. Should the `sum()` be changed?

Comment: ')' in the wrong place

Comment: That is a typo. The problem is that it counts all the shifts, and not the successive shifts. Ofcourse a nurse is allowed to work more then 12 hours, but not consecutively.